# OpenGL Indexed VBO Rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I am getting a completely black screen while trying to draw a simple square in OpenGL.  These methods are called before creation of the buffers:

```
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glOrtho(0.0f, windowX, windowY, 0.0f, 1000.0f, 0);
```

I am creating the buffers like so:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> indices;
std::vector<unsigned int> vertices;    

vertices.push_back(0);
vertices.push_back(0);
vertices.push_back(0);

vertices.push_back(100);
vertices.push_back(0);
vertices.push_back(0);

vertices.push_back(100);
vertices.push_back(100);
vertices.push_back(0);

vertices.push_back(0);
vertices.push_back(100);
vertices.push_back(0);


indices.push_back(0);
indices.push_back(1);
indices.push_back(2);

indices.push_back(2);
indices.push_back(3);
indices.push_back(0);

glGenBuffers(1, &verticesbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(vertices[0]), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &indicesbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(indices[0]), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Display Function:

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesbuffer);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_INT, 0, &vertices[0]);

glColor3f(1, 0, 0);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &indices[0]);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

I have started using AMD GPU PerfStudio to look through my program's drawing calls, and at the glDrawElements() call, PerfStudio shows me the data behind the vertex and index buffers (the index buffer is apparently completely empty, while the vertex buffer only has one point set to x = y = z = 3.40282e+038 (maximum float value)):

```
Unable to map element array buffer for reading.
GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_SIZE: 3
GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_TYPE: GL_INT
GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_STRIDE: 0
GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_POINTER: 0x0C30F2A8
GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING: 1
BufferState
GL_BUFFER_SIZE: 0
GL_BUFFER_USAGE: GL_STATIC_DRAW
GL_BUFFER_ACCESS: GL_READ_WRITE
GL_BUFFER_MAPPED: GL_FALSE
GL_BUFFER_MAP_POINTER: 0x00000000
```

Obviously some of these values are incorrect, I just can't figure out why they didn't come out as they were intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This must have come up before, but I couldn't find a clear duplicate with a quick search.

The problem is here:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesbuffer);
...
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &indices[0]);
```

When a `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is bound during a `glDrawElements()` call, which is the case in your code, the last argument of `glDrawElements()` is an **offset into the index buffer**. What you are passing is the CPU address of the index buffer.

If you want to use the index buffer from its start, which is the right thing to do in your case, the offset should be 0:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Very similarly, this is also broken:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesbuffer);
...
glVertexPointer(3, GL_INT, 0, &vertices[0]);
```

Again, when a `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is bound, the last argument to `glVertexPointer()` is an offset into the buffer. So this should be:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_INT, 0, 0);
```

BTW, using integers for vertex coordinates is rather unusual in OpenGL. It looks like it's supported, so it should work. But it is much more common, and possibly more efficient, to use `GLfloat`/`GL_FLOAT` for the coordinates.

Comment: After making the change to the glDrawElements() call, I still get the same thing.

Comment: @ArcaneEnforcer There's a second similar problem. See update.

Comment: That changed the value of GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_POINTER to 0x00000000, which I believe is correct, but still it is unable to render the polygon and gives me "Unable to map element array buffer for reading."